# Create table and immediately output the results [db2-400]

Tags: .net, db2-400

I first would like to mention that I am in a very heavy black box environment.  There is a stored procedure on the as400 that runs this query at a later date.  There is another process that requires a table be created, followed by returning the output.  How all of this works is beyond my control.

I can only do one thing, pass in a query to the stored proc that creates a table and then do a select on it.

I am trying to create a table with data and immediately output the results all in 1 statement.

This is the same error in both the client tool and when I use the .net app to send the command.

I am running into a roadblock where it is telling me `Message: [SQL0104] Token ; was not valid. Valid tokens: <END-OF-STATEMENT>.`

The query would look something like this:

```
 CREATE table newTable as (select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.foreignId) with data;
 SELECT * from newTable;
```

Now I know the issue is not that the token is not valid, because I can use it for other statements.  I am going to assume it is because I cannot create and select in the same batch.

I have also tried wrapping it in a BEGIN END statement, and I get `Message: [SQL0029] INTO clause missing from embedded statement.`

I am now out of ideas as to how I can do this all on statement.  I have an entirely different issue with sending it in multiple statements where I cannot guarantee the order in which these statements will fire.   This is outside of anything I can unfortunaly change.

I do not have the option to make any modifications to the database except creating a table.  This is a legacy system we still use, and the only purpose is to create reports.  This process has to be via creating a table and returning the result.

To add some clarity.  I personally do not need the result.

What I have to do, is I generate a dynamic query.  I then take this query, and load it into a special table. I then call a stored proc.  This stored proc then reads from this special table, executes the query I give it.   It then takes the result it gets and sends an email.

Comment: Add more details. You could use a procedure and call that.

Comment: NonQueryResult won't create a result-set, but your batch requires a result-set. Tag the correct Db2-server platform (i-series/as400,  or Db2-for-Z/os,  or Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows).  Edit your question to show the target Db2-version and platform,  and which vendor driver-for-db2 you are using (microsoft, ibm, datadirect etc) and which version.

Comment: @data_henrik procs are not an option, I do not have the ability to modify the database except creating a table

Comment: @mao I will try and see what more info I can get.  Ignore the nonexecutequery part of it,  I am just used the wrong term.  I am simply saying one query with two commands going to database.

Comment: .How is this related to .NET? What is the actual code? If the query is correct, and the table doesn't already exist, `DbCommand.ExecuteReader` would work. The error complains about the SQL query though. `I am simply saying one query with two commands going to database.` that's not "simply". Is that syntax allowed at all? Have you tried executing that statement with a client tool to check its validity?

Comment: @mao bah, it is such a late night.  It is a nonexecutequery.   I am not getting the result back.  I am only feeding this string to a stored proc, and this stored proc then will run it.  It is a very complicated process that they have to email a report.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  this error comes from a client tool the actually execution is done on the 400, I am only using .net to feed the statement.  I personally do not care about the result.

Comment: What is "the client tool"? What is the ".net app", what __code__ does it use to submit the batch?  Which vendor's driver for the Db2 for i-series is in use, and which version?

Comment: @mao IBM iaccess.  The app is a proprietary.net app that I cannot discuss.  The only sql code is what I am telling you,  the vb code i will try to make generic but is very basic and the  vender and version I will try to get when I get access again because I have no idea.  Not a database guy.

Comment: Why are you creating a table at all?  Is there some reason you can't just run the select statement you use in your create table command as the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.  Based on some additional info below, I'm going to assume you can run this as two separate queries but you need to remove the dependency on the second one.  Use this as the first one:

```
select * from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.foreignId
```

And use this as the second one:

```
CREATE table newTable as (
        select * 
        from table1 
        join table2 on table1.id = table2.foreignId)
    with data
```

Comment: I have no control over this, the stored proc requires a table, and then it also requires the results

Comment: The table is to save the report, and the select is used during some email process the proc uses.

Comment: There has to be something you aren't explaining in here.  The problem as you have stated it can't work.  It sounds like this report process is working for other reports.  Is there some reason you can't replicate how they do it?

Comment: What I am doing is new.  My company is trying to make use of an old stored proc to do something new.  The proc I call stores queries passed in and runs it one query at a time.  My problem is I cant guarantee order, and I need to create the table before I can select it.  If I just pass in a table, it will create it and not fire an email.  If I create a select, it will fire an email but not create a table. If I do a create, then a select as 2 queries, I run into the issue of selecting a table that does not exist because order is not guaranteed

Comment: You still haven't explained why you need to create a table.  I'm going to assume you need it for some other process because you don't describe any reason to need it for the emailing process.

Comment: “The table is to save the report”.    These Tables are reports.  So when another process needs X report, it is doing a select on X table.

Comment: I have updated my answer.  It sounds like you both want to email out the current data as well as create a copy in a table for future reports.  This is probably the best solution I can give you for that case.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was hoping to avoid, but it may be the only approach.  These tables take days to run,  running it twice may hurt but I can at least tell my hire ups there are no other options.

Comment: It takes days to run these SQL statements?  How much data are you talking about here?  Runtime like that sounds like you need some other solution entirely.  For a runtime of days, I would assume you are looking at petabytes of data or something ridiculously suboptimal in your processing.

Comment: It is a lot of data across a series of databases.  None of it is my concern.